# How do I disable auto-correction from android devices in <input> tag?

Tags: android, html, autocomplete, autocorrect

I have an `<input>` tag on my html page. You are supposed to write various commands inside to send them later on. Commands, obviously, don't always match English and it's a giant problem for my android device. Because it always tries to auto-correct (and I don't want to add words like "changeValue chosenMode,gas" in my keyboard dictionary)

Apparently, `autocomplete=off` and `spellcheck="false"` is not working to prevent auto-correction.

```
<input id="commandInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"/>
```

I also tried `autocorrect="off"`, but it didn't change anything as well. In fact, it's not even a correct property to an input as it seems.
Is there a way to prevent auto-correction?